# Display differences on different computers/devices - background image and button

Tags: css, display

This site http://gaudetelectricllc.com is displayed differently in Chrome depending on the computer or phone used.

On most in Chrome and, apparently all, in FF, Edge, Opera, a background image and text/button with color ffff00 (yellow) are displayed. On some computers/devices using Chrome (same version), the image is not displayed and the text color is black.

I am attaching a comparative image. The left side shows what some Chrome users see and the right what everyone else sees.
[image shows the correct display on right and the problem on the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lD2i.png)

I have no ideas about the cause of the problem.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this bug on my machine; the website loads fine according to the image you posted.  If you're able to reproduce this bug in certain Chrome browsers, consider copying the CSS styles of the elements you mentioned from both working and non-working versions of the page (you can do this using a tool such as Chrome Developer Tools).  Then, edit your question to include the CSS you copied from the working and non-working pages.  This will help others to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks. It's on my client's machine that it doesn't work. I will need to work through it with him and get back with specifics.